# AWK explanation example

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file:

```
AWK question about the example
```

This command that works well:

```
awk  '{ gsub(/...../, "&\n" ) ; print}' file
AWK q
uesti
on ab
out t
he ex
ample
```

Why this command does not print the same result?

```
awk  '{ gsub(/.{5}/, "&\n" ) ; print}' file
AWK question about the example
```

Why this command does not print the same result?

```
awk -v WIDTH=5 '{ gsub(".{"WIDTH"}", "&\n"); print }' file
AWK question about the example
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `{5}` you need to enable `re-interval` like this:

```
awk --re-interval '{ gsub(/.{5}/, "&\n" ) ; print}' file
awk -v WIDTH=5 --re-interval '{ gsub(".{"WIDTH"}", "&\n"); print }' file
```

You could also use `--posix` too, but it will disable other functions in `awk`

```
awk -v WIDTH=5 --posix '{ gsub(".{"WIDTH"}", "&\n"); print }' file
```

Comment: +1 Also, if you upgrade to Gnu Awk version 4, there is no need to specify `--re-interval` any longer..

Comment: Good point, but it would then be less portable, since most linux distro still is on gawk 3.xx.  Do not ask me why since 4.x has been around for some time.

Comment: You should state that `--re-interval` is the right solution, not `--posix` since though both will enable RE intervals the latter will disable all other useful gawk functionality, e.g. `gensub()`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for input, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fold` command instead of `awk`:

```
fold -w 5 input
```

or if you don't have the input in a file:

```
echo 'AWK question about the example' | fold -w 5
```

*Both Give:*

```
AWK q
uesti
on ab
out t
he ex
ample
```

Comment: You can but does not give an answer on OPs question, why does it not work.

Comment: Correct, but there is a right tool for every problem and you already explained the problem clearly.